# WS02 apim.gateway.environment

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

https://github.com/wso2/k8s-wso2am-operator
followed in setting up the server  instance is up but the apigateway for sandbox/production evnironment routing shows error it shows page not found.below is the configuration which i have done in kubernetes applied ingress controller to route the domain tRaffic with SSL. But gateway it page does shows

```
[[apim.gateway.environment]]
name = "Production and Sandbox",
type = "hybrid" 
display_in_api_console = true
description = "This is a hybrid gateway that handles both production and sandbox token traffic."
show_as_token_endpoint_url = true
service_url = "https://domainname:443/services/ 
ws_endpoint = "ws://wso2apim:9099"
wss_endpoint = "wss://wso2apim:8099"
http_endpoint = "http://wso2apim:32004"
https_endpoint = "https://wso2apim:32003"
```

Comment: how did you access the gateway?

Comment: @ruks we are not able to access the site if i put the domain with the nodeport near http and https end point http_endpoint = "http://wso2apim:32004"
https_endpoint = "https://wso2apim:32003" unable to route the traffic any help can be appreciated.